# The complete indifference by Bitcoin people is making me lose my enthusiasm for Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, news-coverage, promotion, spread

I've been eagerly trying to spread the word about Bitcoin and running "Bitcoin Core" for a decade now. Every day, I hold on to this hope that it's going to explode "any day now"... but it never happens.

Other than the sheer lack of adoption, I also can sense a horrible indifference by the Bitcoin developers. My Bitcoin Core is yet again in some bizarre state where it says "5 days left" (to sync) every day after it's already fully synced and got ready yesterday, and remained "fully synced" until I went to bed. Looking at the clock, I wasn't even asleep for five hours until I came back, started the machine up and yet again: "5 days left"...

The main program, Bitcoin Core, the *core* (no pun intended) of Bitcoin, is just falling apart and never seems to reach a point of being "ready for the masses". Hell, the "masses" at this point barely know what a computer even is. All they have now are these surveillance devices ("smartphones") which are even more fundamentally compromised than our PC hardware and OS (Windows in practice).

I haven't heard a good Bitcoin news in forever. The price remains absurdly low (compared to what should have happened by now), but that's not the main point. I don't know how much longer I can hold on to this hollow, faint hope.

Much like I don't see any enthusiasm for anything else anymore, both developers and users seem to just "chug along" and see this as some kind of "fun little theoretical hobby", whereas I view it as a fight literally between life and death. If I didn't like the banks before, I certainly don't have any more love for them now that they have made it impossible to even *view the account balance* in a programmatic manner. They just keep crippling me, while Bitcoin (my savior) goes nowhere.

I want for Bitcoin Core to be stable. I want for Bitcoin to be adopted and used. I want to never have to use "fiat" money again. But it's not happening. I can't help but feel completely disillusioned at this point. "Let down" by the community; by people overall.

Instead of a wonderful, exciting new future of opportunities, all I see is tumbleweed and indifference from the few walking ghosts from the past who still retain any kind of knowledge of privacy and freedom. Scammers and scumbags have destroyed the reputation of Bitcoin and the "altcoins" are so obscure it's not even meaningful to mention them at all.

What can I possibly do at this point other than sitting around and hoping for people to start caring and not remain slaves? They most certainly don't listen to me, that's for damn sure...

Comment: *"What can I possibly do at this point other than sitting around and hoping"* -- Don't *talk* about what you've tried and failed at. Don't argue. Pick one small well-defined area where a tiny incremental improvement can be made. Put in the personal time and effort to learn how to make that tiny improvement. Make it. Don't expect other busy people to dance to your tune. Be positive in your interactions with people you hope to influence?

Comment: *What can I possibly do at this point other than sitting around and hoping for people to start caring and not remain slaves?* 1. Trolling works better on Twitter, Telegram or Reddit 2. If your concern and question is genuine still should be considered [opinion based](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) 3. Bitcoin, bitcoin and Bitcoin Core are different 4. There are lot of positives which I can share if you are interested 5. Price, Speculation and Market cycles will do their own thing. Your opinion and feelings won't matter.

Answer (score 4):

I could write an essay addressing each of your points but I don't think it is worth my time.

If you want price to go up just wait for the next bull market. The market doesn't care about software improvements in the short term.

If you want to learn about all the software improvements that are happening every day on Bitcoin Core subscribe to [Bitcoin Optech](https://bitcoinops.org/), attend the [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/), check out [transcripts](https://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/) or videos of recent presentations from Bitcoin developers. Your commentary is **extremely** misinformed.

Comment: What exactly is your concern? If you need to troubleshoot your Core software focus on that either here, on IRC, or by opening a GitHub issue. To say Bitcoin Core is "falling apart" and developers are "chugging along" is absolute garbage.